# Web scraping TOR sites using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, tor

I am writing a simple Python code that prints html of TOR sites (*.onion* sites). Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

data = requests.get("<<.onion url>>", proxies=proxies).text
print(data)
```

This works well on some *.onion* sites; however, for some, I am getting the following error:

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Is there a reason why this is not working for some onion sites?

(For example, this url throws an error for the above code: `http://zqktlwi4fecvo6ri.onion`)

Comment: Does it happen every time, even if you use a different TOR circuit? Maybe the site in question is blocking/allowing clients with certain user agent strings, cookies, referee, or other headers.

Comment: For the sites that work, they work every time. For the sites that give an error, they give an error every time. When I try going into that site manually using TOR browser, contents appear right away without any verification or authorization. But, for some reason, scrapping html contents with python throws an error.

Comment: I'd try inspecting the headers that are being sent by the TOR browser when it accesses the website, and see if you can emulate those with your request in Python.